# Password Checker improvement

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements, passwords, password-checker

**1.Problem...Its my password validation.COnsoleApp**
*But i have bug....if first space is null program working(...but i want return false if first char is white*

**2.Many Condition using**
*I wanna few using condition..i wanna practise good way*

```
        {
            bool symb = false;
            bool letdig = false;
            char currentchar;
            char currentchar2;
            if (!(pass.Length >= 8 && pass.Length <= 25))
            {
                return true;
            }
            string symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:<>|./?.";
            char[] simbolchar = symbols.ToCharArray();


            for (int j = 0; j < pass.Length; j++)
            {
                currentchar = pass[j];
                foreach (var simb in simbolchar)
                {
                    if (simb == currentchar)
                    {
                        symb = true;
                    }
                }
                if (symb)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pass.Length; i++)
                    {
                        currentchar2 = pass[i];
                        if (char.IsUpper(currentchar2) && (char.IsLetterOrDigit(currentchar2)))
                        {
                            letdig = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (letdig)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("WELCOME");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return letdig;

        }
```

Comment: try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Read about [chain of responsibility](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility)

Answer (score 0):

Solve the first bug can be by adding a condition to check if the string is null or empty before any check after that

```
        public static bool passwordCheck(string pass)
        {
        bool symb = false;
        bool letdig = false;
        char currentchar;
        char currentchar2;
        //Solve the first bug
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pass))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!(pass.Length >= 8 && pass.Length <= 25))
            {
                return true;
            }
            string symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:<>|./?.";
            char[] simbolchar = symbols.ToCharArray();


            for (int j = 0; j < pass.Length; j++)
            {
                currentchar = pass[j];
                foreach (var simb in simbolchar)
                {
                    if (simb == currentchar)
                    {
                        symb = true;
                    }
                }
                if (symb)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pass.Length; i++)
                    {
                        currentchar2 = pass[i];
                        if (char.IsUpper(currentchar2) && (char.IsLetterOrDigit(currentchar2)))
                        {
                            letdig = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (letdig)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("WELCOME");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return letdig;
        }
    }
```

As for code optimization, you can reading about **clear code** for your case